# AWS Log Analytics alternative wiht Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I would like to build my own log analytics like the one proposed by aws but without any of aws services. I was considering Apache Flink as it has similar sql capabilities. Basically would like to replace Amazon Kinesis with Apache Flink. Is it the correct approach.

If so how would I ship my log to Apache Flink?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply replace Amazon Kinesis Analytics by Apache Flink since Flink has a [Kinesis connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/connectors/kinesis.html). If you would like to replace also Kinesis, then I would recommend you to use [Apache Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/) to ingest your data and to read from via Flink's [Kafka connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/connectors/kafka.html).

Comment: Thanks for the feed back want be the best way to send logs in linux systems to Kafka